# Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8> exception when trying to parse object to JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am having a strange problem when trying to parse a swift object to JSON data.

Long story short: I have object whose properties are all declared as Optional:

```
import Foundation

struct SrmaTaskStruct : JSONSerializable{
    var workOrderID : Int?
    var taskNum : Int?
    var taskName: String?
    var editable : Bool?
    var project : SrmaProjectStruct?
    var dates : [String]?
    var realizacije : [RealizacijaStruct]?

    var pctOfCompletionTask: CLong?
    var creationDate: Date?
    var createdBy: String?
    var lastUpdateDate: Date?
    var lastUpdatedBy: String?
    var endEstimate: Date?
    var endWork: Date?
    var minuteEstimate: CLong?
    var minuteWork: CLong?
    var startEstimate: Date?
    var startWork: Date?
    var priority: CLong?
    var text: String?
    var solution: String?
    var idRoleSpecialist: CLong?
    var idRoleSpecialistAssign: CLong?
    var idWorkType: CLong?
    var idMetActivity: CLong?
    var urgent: String?

    init(workOrderID: Int?, taskNum : Int?, taskName : String?, editable : Bool?, project : SrmaProjectStruct, dates : [String]?, realizacije : [RealizacijaStruct]?) {
        self.workOrderID = workOrderID
        self.taskNum = taskNum
        self.taskName = taskName
        self.editable = editable
        self.project = project
        self.dates = dates
        self.realizacije = realizacije
        self.idMetActivity = 0
    }

    init(workOrderID: Int?, idMetActivity: CLong?, idWorkType: CLong?, urgent: String?, idRoleSpecialistAssign: CLong?, idRoleSpecialist: CLong?,
         startEstimate: Date?, endEstimate: Date?, minuteEstimate: CLong?, pctOfCompletionTask: CLong?, text: String?) {
        self.workOrderID = workOrderID
        self.idMetActivity = idMetActivity
        self.idWorkType = idWorkType
        self.urgent = urgent
        self.idRoleSpecialistAssign = idRoleSpecialistAssign
        self.idRoleSpecialist = idRoleSpecialist
        self.startEstimate = startEstimate
        self.endEstimate = endEstimate
        self.minuteEstimate = minuteEstimate
        self.pctOfCompletionTask = pctOfCompletionTask
        self.text = text

    }

}
```

, and during initialization some of them are set to non-Optional values:

```
var task = SrmaTaskStruct(workOrderID: (workOrder?.workOrderId)!, idMetActivity: CLong((discipline?.disciplineId)!), idWorkType: CLong((discipline?.workTypeId)!), urgent: urgent, idRoleSpecialistAssign: CLong((employer?.roleId)!), idRoleSpecialist: CLong((employee?.roleId)!), startEstimate: startEstimate!, endEstimate: endEstimate!, minuteEstimate: minuteEstimate!, pctOfCompletionTask: CLong(0), text: text!)
```

Then, I am calling a JSONSerializable toJSON():

```
let jsonData = task.toJSON()!
```

function accordant to [this article](http://www.sthoughts.com/2016/06/30/swift-3-serializing-swift-structs-to-json/). As a result, I get the

```
 function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
```

exception because this code

```
guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(representation) else {
            return nil
}
```

in toJSON() function returns nil.

To me, it looks like JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject() function returns false because of Optional properties, but I don't understand why this happens because it works in other cases.

What am I missing? Can anybody help please?

Comment: Why don't you use Swift4 and the `Codable` protocol for parsing objects to/from JSON?

Comment: I don't know, I'm pretty new to swift and iOS programming. Person who worked on this project before me used JSONSerializable's utilities so I'm pretty much learning from their code. I get the basics of the JSONSerializable but I don't get why it wont parse this object when it's working elsewhere in project

Comment: initialize everything with 0 and blank string, and shudnt there be a map function for SwiftyJson. how are you getting toJSON support